# can not open smart git on ubuntu

Tags: git, gitlab

trying to start smart git on ubuntu 18.04 LTS on terminal it says.

> ./smartgit.sh: line 44: uname: command not found

but when run the command of line no 44 which is `uname -m` it runs smoothly and display the bits of architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the `PATH` variable where the script is running? You need to make sure that `/bin` is included there, otherwise it cannot find the correct binary to execute.

Maybe can you post more information about this issue? Then it is more likely to find an answer that solves the issue.